# What does Tuple[Hashable] mean in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I came across the following piece of code:

```
def func(self, v: Tuple[Hashable]):
...
```

I know `v: Tuple` would mean variable v must be of type Tuple, but what does `Tuple[Hashable]` mean? Isn't a tuple in Python always hashable?

Comment: Just a point of clarification, “variable v *must* be of type Tuple” (italics mine) is inaccurate as this is simply a *type annotation* and not enforced at runtime.  It’s a hint to help the user / caller of the function use it as designed.

Comment: The "must be" relation can be understood to assume enforcement of static typing using a tool like `mypy`, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tuple is only hashable if the values in the tuple are hashable themselves.

```
>>> hash((1,2))
-3550055125485641917
>>> hash(([1],2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: No, a tuple whose elements are hashable would be `Tuple[Hashable, ...]`. `Tuple[Hashable]` is a type hint for a tuple with *exactly one* element, which must be hashable.

Comment: (This is unlikely to be the correct annotation for whatever the original code is.)

Comment: (Also, strictly speaking, `Hashable` just means the type provides a `__hash__` method. It doesn't require than an object actually be hashable. `([1, 2], [3, 4])` is `Hashable` even though it's unhashable, and `(([1, 2], [3, 4]),)` would satisfy `Tuple[Hashable]`.)

Comment: (Plus, `Hashable` doesn't satisfy subtype transitivity, so `x: object = [1, 2]; y: Hashable = x` type checks even though `list` doesn't provide a `__hash__` method.)

Comment: All good points. I will just remove the last sentence.

Comment: (I wonder if the original code *intended* for `Tuple[Hashable]` to be a tuple of hashables, if not a 1-tuple containing a hashable value.)

Comment: "Also, strictly speaking, Hashable just means the type provides a \__hash__ method." does not make sense to me. In the docs it says that a `hashable` needs a `__hash__` method (which is obvious). However, it also needs to have a valid hash value, in contrast to a `TypeError: unhashable type : 'list'`.

Comment: @BcK That's a runtime effect caused by the execution of `tuple.__hash__`. You can *call* the `__hash__` method of any tuple, but it's not guaranteed to return a hash value. So without `__hash__` method, no instance of  type is hashable. With a `__hash__` method, an instance of the type *might* be hashable.

Comment: Only in a language like Idris (which does not support partial functions) can you write a function that is guaranteed at the type level to always return a value. Python is not such a language.

Comment: @chepner Well, imho, that proves the method itself _is_ a prerequisite and its sole existence is not the complete definition for a hashable.